# Rearranging a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I would like to convert a matrix which has a structure like this:

```
{{"A", 10, "D", 1},{"B", 3, "A", 2},{"C", 7, "B", 3},{"D", 6, "C", 4}}//MatrixForm//Print;
```

into one that looks like this:

```
{{"A", 10, "A", 2},{"B", 3, "B", 3},{"C", 7, "C", 4},{"D", 6, "D", 1}}//MatrixForm//Print;
```

Is there a way to do this that still works even if column 1 is not in alphabetical order?

Comment: You can remove `// Print;` at the end - still get same visual.

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi that should be an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite saying

> Coloumn 3 should look like coloumn 1

it seems your rearrangement from your first list to the second is much more than that because you are moving **both** the third and fourth elements. In other words you are not simply making column 3 the same as column 1. So therefore you need to rearrange while keeping the 3rd and 4th elements grouped together:

```
list = {{"A", 10, "D", 1}, {"B", 3, "A", 2}, {"C", 7, "B", 3}, {"D", 
   6, "C", 4}};
list[[All, {3, 4}]] = SortBy[list[[All, {3, 4}]], First];
list

(* {{"A", 10, "A", 2}, {"B", 3, "B", 3}, {"C", 7, "C", 4}, {"D", 6, "D", 
  1}} *)
```

[image]

**Edit**

Okay let's consider a case in which column 1 is not in alphabetical order.

```
list = {{"D", 10, "C", 1}, {"B", 3, "A", 2}, {"C", 7, "B", 3}, {"A", 
    6, "D", 4}};
```

Based on your example the transformed list should be

```
{{"D", 10, "D", 4}, {"B", 3, "B", 3}, {"C", 7, "C", 1}, {"A", 6, "A", 
  2}}
```

...right?

In this case you collect the order of your first column and use that later:

```
order = Ordering[list[[All, 1]]]
(*  {4, 2, 3, 1}  *)
```

Then proceed as above by sorting the grouped columns 3 and 4 and then arrange that sorted list according to the order of column 1.

```
list[[All, {3, 4}]] = SortBy[list[[All, {3, 4}]], First][[order]];
list

(* {{"D", 10, "D", 4}, {"B", 3, "B", 3}, {"C", 7, "C", 1}, {"A", 6, "A", 
  2}} *)
```

Alternatively the final step could be written as

```
list[[order, {3, 4}]] = SortBy[list[[All, {3, 4}]], First];
list
```

[image]

Comment: Attentive, I hadn't realised +1

Comment: thx for the nice answer. sorry that I didn't mention that column 4 should change as well

Answer (score 1):

Starting with:

```
in = {{"A", 10, "D", 1}, {"B", 3, "A", 2}, {"C", 7, "B", 3}, {"D", 6, "C", 4}};
```

A method using [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GatherBy.html):

```
Join @@@ GatherBy[Join @@ Partition[in, {4, 2}][[1]], First]
```

> ```
> {{"A", 10, "A", 2}, {"B", 3, "B", 3}, {"C", 7, "C", 4}, {"D", 6, "D", 1}}
> ```

And a method using the new-in-10 [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Association.html) functionality:

```
Merge[{# -> #2, #3 -> #4} & @@@ in\[Transpose], # &]

Join @@@ Thread /@ List @@@ Normal[%]
```

> ```
> <|"A" -> {10, 2}, "B" -> {3, 3}, "C" -> {7, 4}, "D" -> {6, 1}|>
>
> {{"A", 10, "A", 2}, {"B", 3, "B", 3}, {"C", 7, "C", 4}, {"D", 6, "D", 1}}
> ```